# The correlated scalar subquery can only contain equality predicates issue with spark sql

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

```
select *,
      (select sum(my_val) from my_data data1
      where my_date > date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 180)
      and my_date < date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 90)
      and data2.id = data1.id ) as changed_1,
      (select sum(my_val) from my_data data1
      where my_date > date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 160)
      and my_date < date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 150)
      and data2.id = data1.id ) as changed_2,
      (select sum(my_val) from my_data data1
      where my_date > date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 80)
      and my_date < date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 45)
      and data2.id = data1.id ) as changed_3
      ...<insert a lot of other aggregations based on different date ranges>...
from otherdata_data data2
```

I am trying to execute the above sql, however I get the following error

```
The correlated scalar subquery can only contain equality predicates
```

I have 50 or so aggregate sub queries all based on different parameters between `my_data` and `otherdata_data` each aggregation will be on a different date range and some other possible factors.  Is it possible to do this in spark sql since it doesnt seem to like non-equalities in sub queries of a predicate?

Answer (score 1):

how about chnage your query to this:

```
select
    data2.*,
       sum(case when data1.my_date > data1.date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 180) and data1.my_date < data1.date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 90) then my_val end)  as changed_1,
       sum(case when data1.my_date > data1.date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 160) and data1.my_date < data1.date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 150) then my_val end) as changed_2,
       sum(case when data1.my_date > data1.date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 80) and data1.my_date < data1.date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 45) then my_val end) as changed_3
from
    otherdata_data data2
    join my_data data1
     on data2.id = data1.id
group by <all columns of otherdata_data table>
```

Comment: Thanks! For the group by, `otherdata_data` is unique on lets call them `col_a`+`col_b` should i just be grouping by that?

Comment: @asdasd32 , only group by the columns you want in the select

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select data1.id,
       sum(case when my_date > date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 180) and my_date < date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 90)
                then my_val
           end),
       sum(case when my_date > date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 160) and my_date < date_sub(CAST(data2.start_date as DATE), 150)
                then my_val
           end),
       . . . 
from data1
group by data1.id;
```

You can then join in other tables (perhaps using this as a subquery).